# Difference between private property and method holding static value?

Tags: php

**Private variable**

```
class Input {
    private
        $form;

    public function __construct (Form $form) {
        $this->form = $form;
    }

    public function getForm () {
        return $this->form;
    }
}
```

**Method with static variable**

```
class Input {
    public function __construct (Form $form) {
        $this->getForm($form);
    }

    public function getForm (Form $set_form = null) {
        static $form;

        if (!$form && $set_form !== null) {
            $form = $set_form;
        } else if ($form && $set_form) {
            throw new \ErrorException('Form has been already set.');
        }

        return $form;
    }
}
```

I prefer the latter because `$form` property is not included when you are dumping the `Input` object. Because of their circular relation (not shown in the example), it makes the output unreadable.

What are the disadvantages of using the latter approach VS the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` variable in a method is constant **across all instances of the class**, a `private` property is simply not accessible from outside the class, but unique to each instance of it. They're not the same at all. If you need a property which is unique to each classes instance, there's no replacement for a property. It's also much more readable and idiomatic than your `static` workaround for the same thing.

Learn to read `var_dump`s better if that's your only reason to use `static` variables.